# How to specify a static class member as a value of an array property, when defining the array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, static

This won't work:

```
class Someclass {
   public static $v = '28';
   private static $a = Array (
      'theNumber' => self::$v
   );
}
```

it yields:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$v' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or class (T_CLASS)

How can I have `theNumber` use a static member of `Someclass` as a value?

EDIT:
please read the question before answering or "marking as duplicate", this question is not about syntax. It is whether or not it's possible to use a static var in an array (which isn't).

Comment: What version of PHP are you on?

Comment: not the answer, but you should put "theNumber" in quotes

Comment: I'm using version 5.5

Comment: (It's with quotes now)

Comment: @John Conde - I don't see any relation to the question you marked as a duplicate for this question. My question was how it is possible to use a static var as a value of an array, it's not related to syntax (even though I quoted the syntax error) but to functionality. Anyway I now understand that only allowing to use a constant there makes sense, functionality-wise (since the array is initialized when the class is initialized). The solution to the question is to simply add a function to the class, that changes that specific property of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a constant:

```
class Someclass {
   const NUM = '28';
   public static $v = NUM;
   private static $a = Array (
      'theNumber' => NUM
   );
}
```

Comment: What if I want that value to be changeable when using the class?

Comment: @YuvalA., you cannot change a const but you can change the two static values. If you mean you want both static values to change automatically when you change a third variable, then you cannot do this either.